# Path integral question

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

For $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{z^3+1}$ and $\gamma(t)=Re^{it}$ with $t \in [0,\pi]$

I should prove that $\lim_{R \to \infty} |\int_\gamma f(z) dz|=0$

I tried to use $\int_\gamma f(z) dz=F(\gamma(\pi))-F(\gamma(0))$ with the primitive

$F(z)=-\frac{1}{6}ln|z^2-z+1|+\frac{1}{3}ln|z+1|+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan(\frac{2z-1}{\sqrt{3}})$
but as $R\to\infty$ i get $-\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$

(and $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}$ with absolute value)

What is/are the problem/s with my calculations?
Do i have to use absolute value for the argument of arctan? If so, i missed this part in calculus...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$\int |f| \ne |F|$$
Is your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use parametrisation:

$$\left|\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^3+1}\;dz\right|=\left|i\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{Re^{it}}{1+(Re^{it})^3}\;dt\right|\leq \int_{0}^{\pi}\left|\frac{Re^{it}}{1+(Re^{it})^3}\right|\;dt$$

But:

$$\left|\frac{Re^{it}}{1+(Re^{it})^3}\right|=\frac{|Re^{it}|}{|1+(Re^{it})^3|}\leq \frac{|Re^{it}|}{|1|-|(Re^{it})^3|}=\frac{R}{1-R^3} \to 0$$

when $R \to \infty$.